# mod_rewrite for clean URL's not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have looked at every question and every example of reWriteRule for an apache server...  Nothing has worked.

I just need to change
http://beta.EXAMPLE.com/profile.php?profile_name=ntgCleaner
to
http://beta.EXAMPLE.com/ntgCleaner

I have to see if [my .htaccess file is being read](http://jappler.com/blog/archive/2008/10/22/how-to-test-htaccess-files) and checked to see [if mod_rewrite is enabled](http://lynnepope.net/check-if-mod_rewrite-enabled-on-server) and they both work perfectly fine.

For some reason, the examples that I have come across are not working for me.  Here are some of the examples.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /(.*)$ /profile.php?username=$1
```

,

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^profile\/(.*)$ ./profile.php?profileId=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

and

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=10
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?profile_name=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?profile_name=$1
```

But none of these work.  Is this because I am using a subdomain?  I plan on eventually switching over the subdomain from BETA to just www when I finish the site.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /profile.php?profile_name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Your examples have a lot of different query strings in it, so I'm not sure which one is the one you really want. You have `?username=`, `?profileId=`, `?profile_name=`.

Comment: Oh sorry, I just want it to use the profile_name as the clean url, so from example.com/profile.php?profile_name=ntgCleaner to example.com/ntgCleaner

Those we just the examples I was going with

Comment: That is exactly what I needed!  I didn't think request_filename had to do with anything...  Thank you!

Comment: @ntgCleaner it's a way to not infinitely loop, because it won't re-rewrite if the URI points to an existing resource (like profile.php).

Answer (score 0):

You must use condition (RewriteCond) and when is condition met, rule (RewriteRule) is applicated. So, when you don't use condition, rule is not used, because engine don't know for what to use it.

RewriteCond must be used before RewriteRule, I use it against web-bots in this form:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} .googlebot.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} .search.msn.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} .kimsufi.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /errors/404.html [F]
```